# Jquery offset as coordinates for svg line

Tags: jquery, svg, line, coordinates, offset

How I can use the jquery offset as coordinates of a svg line?

For example, when using the offsets {top: 69, left: 9} and {top: 69, left: 223} and insert them in svg coordinates of the line, the line position is not the same offset

The offset.top is the y coordinate and offset.left is the x coordinate

```
<svg>
    <line x1="9" y1="69" x2="223" y2="68" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: offset of which element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you already has offset values. give some `id` ti the line and from jquery you can use this is as selector to manipulate the attributes.

try this.

```js
var offset1 = {
  top: 69,
  left: 9
};

var offset2 = {
  top: 69,
  left: 223
};

$('#line').attr({
  "x1": offset1.left,
  "y1": offset1.top,
  "x2": offset2.left,
  "y2": offset2.top
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <line id='line' x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

just saw your fiddle.to draw a line between those two tables,make the position of `svg` `absolute` and make the `z-index:-1`.so `svg` will stay behind the two tables.

check this snippet

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  $("#log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <line id="line" x1="45" y1="20" x2="200" y2="20" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td id="hiA">Hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>How</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ok</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="ola3" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td id="hiB">Hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>How</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ok</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am trying to do is connect two tables with an svg line, but I'm can't to put the line between the two tables.  
https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelcb21/61tou8om/